# may I please know what would be the benefit of redirecting to a web service url that Does not have the .svc extension?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, silverlight, rest, redirect

I recenlty created a RESTful service using Microsoft WCF for a Silverlight module used in an Microsoft ASP.NETapplication

I would get an ugly looking url like the following when I invoke the web service:

https://www.blahblah.com/blahblahSilverlightServiceblahblah.svc/IblahSilverlightService/retrieveusername

Some technical articles, blogs and forums suggest that I use the Microsoft URL ReWrite module to redirect the RESTful service in such a way that it would use a url that Does not have the .svc extension.

Other than the fact that the url is diffcult to read, and quite long, may I please know what would be the benefit of redirecting to a web service url that Does not have the .svc extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is most defiantly aesthetics since for the most part REST services are use to talk computer to computer.  But to add a little meat to this comment I will say instead of using the svc method you have used you could instead use the factory method to get the clean URL's I think you want.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb412178(v=vs.90).aspx

> "http://localhost:8000/EchoWithGet?s=Hello, world!"